# why UIModalPresentationCustom cause screen to blank

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, uiviewanimationtransition

I have a transition animation while presenting a view. But when I give " viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom" , the screen goes blank after dismissing the view. The dismissing animations works perfectly but after completion the window goes blank. If I commented that line, its works like a charm. Why is its so? Whats then the use of UIModalPresentationCustom ? can anyone explain please. Thanks in Advance